# C# .NET socket tcp begin/endreceive client : endreceive reads all bytes, but in beginreceive, the buffer size changes on its own

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, sockets, asynchronous

so i have a server and client using the class Socket (on tcp).

I've been struggling with this problem for a few weeks, I've searched a lot but I don't understand how that problem is possible. I've been watching debugger a lot, watching values of my variables but can't see where the problem is.

For example, the client sends 100 bytes, and the server receives them, proceeds them and send back 150 bytes. But, on client side, the buffer changes size each time the client receives a message (i don't know why, maybe because of beginreceive).

So, when the server sends these 150 bytes, the client beginreceive, but I see that the buffer size is 100 (same size as the previous message the client has sent).

And the client does "endreceive", and read 150 bytes (the right amount of bytes sent by server).

When i want to get the string, i use an encoding function, the buffer containing message, and the number of bytes received.

So, i end up having **a buffer of size of 100 bytes (wrong size) and the number of bytes read is 150 bytes (right amount).**

I've modified my code many times, tried to define "new byte[bufferSize]", but the problem stays the same.

Sometimes, the client even receive message that the server has never sent! That's weird. The client seems sometimes to receive bytes from the "server buffer" (i haven't found how to check it)

```
       public void InitializeReceive(Socket soc)
        {
             //bufferSize is fixed to 256
            MyBuffer = new byte[bufferSize];

            soc.BeginReceive(MyBuffer , 0, MyBuffer .Length,
                SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(Receiving), soc);

        }
        public void Receiving(IAsyncResult iar)
        {

            Socket tmp = (Socket)iar.AsyncState;

            int received= tmp.EndReceive(iar);

            if (received> 0)
            {
                 //problem is here. MyBuffer has a size of 100 bytes, received is 150 bytes
                string msg = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(MyBuffer, 0, received);



                //next message
                InitializeReceive(tmp);
            }

        }
```

i've tried checking heap stack, stuff like this too, but i don't really know how to diagnostic it.

The first messages between client and server are okay. But it becomes like this after a few exchanges, and the buffer that i fixed isn't full at all. The size of  first messages were around 36 bytes, over 100 bytes, and so on. It doesn't seem to be a problem of size here

I don't even understand how it is possible. I hope someone has an explanation thank you !

**EDIT :**

So, as asked, I tried to make a minimal reproducible code.

I've tested it myself and yes, the problem still stays. I get the exception "System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException " in the client side.

Server code :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
//
using System.Net;
using System.Net.NetworkInformation;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;

namespace BugServeurSocket1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private Socket MonServeur, MonClient;


        int bufferSize = 256;
        private byte[] MonBuffer;

        int portServeur = 8000;

        string tAdversaire = "1";

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MonBuffer = new byte[bufferSize];

            #region mise en place serveur
  
            IPAddress IPServeur = CorrectAddress(Dns.GetHostName());

            MonServeur = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

            MonServeur.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPServeur, portServeur));

            MonServeur.Listen(10);

            MonServeur.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(SurDemandeConnexion), MonServeur);
            #endregion
        }

        //réseau
        #region fct perso
        #region verif adr ipv4
        private IPAddress CorrectAddress(string nPC)
        {
            IPAddress ipReponse = null;

            if (nPC.Length > 0)
            {
                IPAddress[] IPserveur = Dns.GetHostEntry(nPC).AddressList;

                for (int i = 0; i < IPserveur.Length; i++)
                {
                    Ping pingServeur = new Ping();
                    //envoyer ping
                    PingReply pingResponse = pingServeur.Send(IPserveur[i]);

                    if (pingResponse.Status == IPStatus.Success)

                        if (IPserveur[i].AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
                        {

                            ipReponse = IPserveur[i];
                            break;
                        }
                }//for
            }

            return ipReponse;
        }
        #endregion
        #region reception connexion client
        public void SurDemandeConnexion(IAsyncResult iar)
        {
            Socket tmp = (Socket)iar.AsyncState;

            MonServeur.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(SurDemandeConnexion), MonServeur);//accepter nouvelles connexions

            MonClient = tmp.EndAccept(iar);

            //MonBuffer = new byte[256];//test
            MonBuffer = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes("Connexion acceptée");
            MonClient.Send(MonBuffer, 0, MonBuffer.Length, SocketFlags.None);

            //ver7
            InitializeReceive(MonClient);
        }
        #endregion
        public void InitializeReceive(Socket soc)
        {
            MonBuffer = new byte[256];//empty buffer//test

            soc.BeginReceive(MonBuffer, 0, MonBuffer.Length,
                SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(ReceiveMsg), soc);
        }
        public void ReceiveMsg(IAsyncResult iar)
        {
            Socket tmp = (Socket)iar.AsyncState;

            int received = tmp.EndReceive(iar);

            if (received > 0)
            {
                string msg = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(MonBuffer, 0, received);

                string[] msgSplit = msg.Split(':');

                //pseudo
                string msgKey = msgSplit[0];

                #region recherche adversaire
                if (msgKey == "JEU_CHERCHER_ADVERSAIRE")
                {
                        MonBuffer = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes("TESTJEU_CHERCHER_ADVERSAIRE:" + tAdversaire + ":"
+ tAdversaire + "=adversaire_RECHERCHE;joueur_RECHERCHANT");

                       MonClient.Send(MonBuffer, 0, MonBuffer.Length, SocketFlags.None);
                }
                #endregion

                //next msg
                InitializeReceive(tmp);
            }
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

Client code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;
using System.IO; 
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Threading;
//
using System.Net;
using System.Net.NetworkInformation;
using System.Net.Sockets;

namespace BugClientSocket1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private Socket MonClient;

        //buffer
        int bufferSize = 256;
        private byte[] MonBuffer;

        int portServeur = 8000;

        string pseudoID = "1:";
        string tAdversaire = "1";

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            tPseudo.Text = pseudoID;

            MonBuffer = new byte[bufferSize];
        }

        private IPAddress CorrectAddress(string nPC)
        {
            IPAddress ipReponse = null;

            try
            {
                if (nPC.Length > 0)
                {
                    IPAddress[] IPserveur = Dns.GetHostEntry(nPC).AddressList; 
                    for (int i = 0; i < IPserveur.Length; i++)
                    {
                        Ping pingServeur = new Ping();
                        PingReply pingResponse = pingServeur.Send(IPserveur[i]);

                        if (pingResponse.Status == IPStatus.Success)
                            if (IPserveur[i].AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
                            {
                                ipReponse = IPserveur[i];
                                break;
                            }
                    }//for
                }

                return ipReponse;
            }
            catch (SocketException e)
            {
                return null;
            }
        }

        private void BConnecter_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MonClient = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

            MonClient.Blocking = false;


            //tserveur.txt -> replace with your PC name
            IPAddress IPserveur = CorrectAddress(tServeur.Text);

            if (IPserveur != null)
                MonClient.BeginConnect(new IPEndPoint(IPserveur, portServeur), new AsyncCallback(OnConnection), MonClient);

        }
        #region Se connecter au serveur
        public void OnConnection(IAsyncResult iar)
        {
            Socket tmp = (Socket)iar.AsyncState;

            if (tmp.Connected)
            {
                byte[] msg = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes("PSEUDO:" + tPseudo.Text);

                //send pseudo
                MonClient.Send(msg, 0, msg.Length, SocketFlags.None);

                //next msg
                InitializeReceive(tmp);

            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Serveur inaccessible");
            }

        }
        #endregion
        #region Debut reception msg + suite
        //cfr beginaccept-> beginreceive ici
        public void InitializeReceive(Socket soc)
        {
            MonBuffer = new byte[bufferSize];

            soc.BeginReceive(MonBuffer, 0, MonBuffer.Length,
                SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(ReceiveMsg), soc);

        }
        public void ReceiveMsg(IAsyncResult iar)
        {
            Socket tmp = (Socket)iar.AsyncState;

            int received = tmp.EndReceive(iar);

            if (received > 0)
            {
                string msg = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(MonBuffer, 0, received);

                //next msg
                InitializeReceive(tmp);
            }

        }
        #endregion

        private void BChercher_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (MonClient != null && tPseudoAdversaire.Text != "")
            {
                //MonBuffer = new byte[bufferSize];
                MonBuffer = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes("JEU_CHERCHER_ADVERSAIRE:" + tAdversaire + ":"
                    + pseudoID + "=adversaire_RECHERCHE;joueur_RECHERCHANT");

                //send pseudo
                MonClient.Send(MonBuffer, 0, MonBuffer.Length, SocketFlags.None);

            }

        }
    }
}
```

I did let text on purpose (such as JEU_CHERCHER...), to get the exact same problem.

My application is a **winform in visual studio 2019**

To reproduce the bug, here the steps:

1. Put breakpoints in method "beginreceive" and "end receive", and variable "received"; to see the number of byte and string. Also check size of MonBuffer when arriving to these break points
2. clic on "connexion" button to connect to server
3. Server receive "pseudo" and accept client
4. Server send message saying "ok you are connected"
5. Clic on "chercher" (search)  to send a new message to server
6. Server got message, proceed it, then answer it with a new message
7. Client receive message, and **here the bug** : **buffer size is smaller than number of received byte**
8. Exception occurs

If you don't understand something (because i didn't translate all in english), please tell me. Thank you

Comment: You are not reusing the same buffer for send and receive?

Comment: Hello, MyBuffer is a global variable.I use that same MyBuffer to send and receive message for the client socket

Comment: Please provide a [MRE]. Very unbelievable. I think you re-assign it somewhere like you re-assign it in `InitializeReceive()`.

Comment: Using same buffer for send and receive doesn't look like a good idea. You need to show how are you using it for send too.

Comment: Please use a proper IDE and run the command "Find usages" on `MyBuffer`. Then put breakpoints on each assignment, each read and each write operation.

Comment: Okay, I'm going to make a minimal reproducible example. I'm using visual studio 2019. I've put breakpoints but it seems the program doesn't go where i think it should

Comment: @ThomasWeller It's done, i made a minimal reproducible example. I've tried it myself, I get the problem i explained in this thread.

Comment: @Evk what is weird is that ,  the first messages exchanged seem fine. I don't know, i tried sending messages in different ways, like a button click, it's fine. When the message's length change,  i get this problem of buffer changing size on its own

Comment: @ThomasWeller and actually i put " new byte[]" in ```InitializeReceive()``` because it solved the problem of not receiving all data at all. If i remove it, something weird is happening too. I can't get whole message  (actually i think it's the same kind problem, the buffer size change; and number of received bytes isn't the same)

Comment: Well in your sample code you initialize buffer with different length right in `BChercher_Click` function. So you start BeginReceive with buffer of length 256, but then on click you change that buffer (or actually you change variable you later check in EndReceive). Just don't use global buffer at all until you get it working (or better never), at the very least don't use same buffer for send and receive

Comment: `MonBuffer = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(...)` is the fatal mistake, makes you lose track of the receive buffer.  Just use a local variable.

Comment: @HansPassant , thank you , i'm so surprised THAT was the solution. I never thought it would be the problem (i was doing this way because in class, the teacher was doing that)

Comment: @Evk thank you too ! It worked. I use ```MonBuffer``` as a global variable for receiving data. All the buffer to send message are local variables. It solved the problem I think, at least the program seems to work , and the buffer doesn't change size anymore (it stays with a size of 256 bytes)

Comment: You are welcome. Note also that the way you work with tcp is flawed - there is no such thing as tcp message, it's a stream of bytes. That means when server sends say 100 bytes - you might NOT receive them on client in one tcp packet. That means your Receive might get for example 50 bytes. For that reason you need some protocol, for example if you exchange text - always end each message with newline. Then the other party reads until newline character appears in the stream (that might require multiple reads). It might appear to work now but it will break.

Comment: @Evk Okay, so, to be sure the entire message is received (or not), the most simple way could be to add a word or something at the end of each message (client/server) ?

i've done some research about it. I might keep "beginreceive" until i read the last word "ENDMESSAGE" (for example). 

Is it a good idea to convert each "stream of bytes" received into string, and concatenate all those strings until message is complete? thank you

Comment: Yes, any marker of message end will do. Note that if you use unicode or other multibyte encoding then converting each packet to string might break too, because in unicode character can span multiple bytes, and so it can happen that character is split between two packets (one byte is at the end of first packet, another is at the beginning of next)

Comment: Another popular indicator is prepend message length (in binary form) in a fixed number of bytes (say 2 or 4, depending on how long your messages can be). Then receiver first reads 2(4) bytes and converts them to number, indicating length of the message. Then it reads exactly that much bytes. And another note - using async/await will make your code much easier to manage, Begin/EndXXX are quite archaic constructs.

Comment: @Evk ok, thank you for your advice. For my next projects, i would use async/await and try to remember those advices for tcp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To sum it up, the solution is:

- Avoid global variable as buffer when possible. But here, I need global variable as buffer for receiving data
- **Never use the same buffer for receive and send message (bytes)**
- **Use local variable to send at least, and here, I use the global variable buffer to receive**